# Python Dataframe: Considering different columnes per row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's assume the columns in the `df` stand for months and the rows are different products which are sold over time (in the months from the columns). See picture below.

**Legend**:

- x: sold items
- 0: nothing sold
- How to get statistical values only from the green part?

[image]

But the different products were not sold over all the time. Some products were not sold after a certain period and some products came to the marked later than others (Life cycle).

Problem: Operations on the df such as `df.mean(axis=1)` go over all the columns. But to do the correct inventory analysis, only the relevant time frame (amount of columns), green in the image, has to be considered in the operations. However, the statistical values computed over the whole period of time will give a wrong image, since a product was not sold over some (the outer) parts of the period.

---

One idea was to do it with iteration in a `for`-loop. But I know this is not the way to treat a df correctly. So does someone know how to treat each row in the data frame differently in order to get the correct statistical values.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], more specific copy/pastable data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC let's try something like:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'c1': {'r1': 0, 'r2': 8, 'r3': 2, 'r4': 0, 'r5': 0},
     'c2': {'r1': 0, 'r2': 2, 'r3': 0, 'r4': 6, 'r5': 0},
     'c3': {'r1': 0, 'r2': 0, 'r3': 9, 'r4': 0, 'r5': 5},
     'c4': {'r1': 0, 'r2': 0, 'r3': 0, 'r4': 2, 'r5': 9},
     'c5': {'r1': 8, 'r2': 0, 'r3': 6, 'r4': 0, 'r5': 0}}
)

# Replace 0s with NaN (Invalidate 0 Values)
# Grab Values Between first valid index and last valid index
# Put the 0s back in between desired range
# Do Aggregate Computation
df['mean'] = df.replace(0, np.nan).apply(
    lambda s: s[s.first_valid_index():s.last_valid_index()].fillna(0).mean(),
    axis=1
)

print(df)
```

Source:

```
    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
r1   0   0   0   0   8
r2   8   2   0   0   0
r3   2   0   9   0   6
r4   0   6   0   2   0
r5   0   0   5   9   0
```

Output:

```
    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5      mean
r1   0   0   0   0   8  8.000000  # 8 / 1
r2   8   2   0   0   0  5.000000  # (8 + 2) / 5
r3   2   0   9   0   6  3.400000  # (2 + 0 + 9 + 0 + 6) / 5
r4   0   6   0   2   0  2.666667  # (6 + 0 + 2) / 3
r5   0   0   5   9   0  7.000000  # (5 + 9) / 2
```

---

If no zeros should be included in the computation drop the `.fillna(0)` in the `apply`.

Comment: Perfect! This was excactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom function that slices the portion of the row between the first and last location of the string `'x'`. Then you can perform whatever custom operation you want, such as the percentage of the string `'x'` in the interior portion of each row.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

## first four rows to show working example
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={'c1':['x']*3+['0'], 'c2':['x']*4, 'c3':['0']+['x']*3, 'c4':['0']*3+['x'], 'c5':['x']*2+['0','x'],
    'c6':['0']+['x']*3, 'c7':['0']*2+['x']*2,'c8':['0']*4,'c9':['0']*4},
    index=['r1','r2','r3','r4']
    )

## perform some operation only the interior of the row
def get_interior_percent(row):
    x_first, x_last = np.where(row=='x')[0][0], np.where(row=='x')[0][-1]
    interior_row = row.iloc[x_first:x_last+1]
    ## you can perform the operation on the interior row
    return sum(interior_row == 'x') / len(interior_row)

df['mean'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_interior_percent(x), axis=1)
```

Result:

```
>>> df
   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9      mean
r1  x  x  0  0  x  0  0  0  0  0.600000
r2  x  x  x  0  x  x  0  0  0  0.833333
r3  x  x  x  0  0  x  x  0  0  0.714286
r4  0  x  x  x  x  x  x  0  0  1.000000
```